# Consulta MYsql Con InnerJoin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Tengo dos tablas en Mysql.

reservas(id,nombre,fechaent,fechasal)
dineros(identificador,id,valor,oper)

donde id de dineros, puede tener varios registros con un mismo id, perteneciente a una unica reserva de la tabla reservas.

Quiero hacer una consulta, donde se muestren todos los registros, entre dos rangos de fechas, de la tabla reservas, pero con un campo adicional de suma, de todos los valores que aparezcan en la tabla dinero, con ese id de la reserva, pero que sume solo sumar, cuando el campo oper='credito'.

Hice un InnerJoin, pero entonces si no existe ninguna operacion en dineros, con el id de la tabla reserva, no me muestra esa reserva, y lo que quiero mas bien que muestre todas las del periodo x al x, y que las que tengan valores en la tabla dineros, los sume. las que no, pues saldria 0 en la sumatoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintáxis básica seria :

```
SELECT nombresDeCampos
FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2
ON tabla1.nombreDeCampo = tabla2.nombreDeCampo;
```

Recuerda que hay muchos tipos de **Joins**. Dependiendo que es lo que ocupes, para ello te recomiendo la siguiente gráfica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sólo comentar: en tu respuesta pusiste ..." hay muchos tipos de inner joins"... pero no es así, hay muchos joins, dependiendo qué necesites: `left join`, `right join`, etc... Saludos!